# UIView drag and ease out

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a view which I can drag around. Now I would like the view to ease out when I stop dragging it so that I get a more natural feeling.

Does anyone have an idea?

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previous = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

    if (!CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(self.transform)) {
        location = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(location, self.transform);
        previous = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(previous, self.transform);
    }

    self.frame = CGRectOffset(self.frame,
                              (location.x - previous.x),
                              (location.y - previous.y));
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Try to view hidden with animation if you dragging stop ?

Comment: No the view should still be displayed

Comment: means you will try to add animation on view after dragging stop ?

Comment: Yes. For example if you flick the view it should just ease out(decelerate)

Comment: use touchesEnded method and add animation on view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on your view to perform the dragging.
you can get the translation via `[recognizer translationInView:yourview]` and the velocity via `[recognizer velocityInView:yourview]`. Apply the translation for the drag-effect and use the velocity to create your desired decelerate-animation.